# CakePHP 3 Create foreign key fields from associations

Tags: cakephp, foreign-keys, associations, cakephp-3.0

I have the following (simplified) code:

```
$book = new Book();
$book->author = $this->Authors->get(XX);
```

The book has the property *author_id*, but this is only set when I save the *$book*.

However, I need to check the author_id property **before** *$book* gets saved.

Is there any CakePHP method that creates the foreign key fields from the associated models or do I have to create this fields manually?

Thank you!

Comment: What exactly does "_check the author_id property_" mean? What kind of "checks" are you referring to? Validation rules? Application rules? ...

Comment: Actually I am synchronizing two databases with different structures. Only one of them is part of my CakePHP App. So I am creating the Entities from the first database, fetch the appropriate entity from the second database and then patch the first object into the second object to check if there are any changes. But, if the autor_id column is not patched, it will not change in the second object, so there is no change registered.

Comment: Sorry, but I still don't fully get the actual problem. Maybe add some real world code that demonstrates the problem in a reproducable way.

Comment: My real world code is about 1000 lines long, that would be too much :-) The comparing of the entities is not the point, I just want to know if there is a function that creates the foreign key fields (like author_id) when I add an associated entity (like author) to the parent entity.